# separating two dates from a single string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string as `August 24, 2014 - September 22, 2014` .

I am aspecting output like:

```
     var start="August 24, 2014";
     var end= "September 22, 2014":   
     alert(start);  alert(end);
```

How to separate like this in java-script/Jquery?

I started trying with this but my my below code did not executed, so i thought to ask your help to solve the above mention question.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var fullDate="August 24, 2014 - September 22, 2014";
        alert(fullDate.replace(-\W/g, ''));


});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js2g4p4h/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**Split**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_split.htm) in javascript

```
 var fullDate="August 24, 2014 - September 22, 2014";

 fullDate = fullDate.split("-");

 var start= fullDate[0];
 var end=  fullDate[1];   

 alert(start);  alert(end);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wdbvkv5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()` as shown below :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var fullDate="August 24, 2014 - September 22, 2014";
    var date = fullDate.split("-");  //here 'date' will be an array having two elements.
    var startdate = date[0];
    var enddate = date[1];
    alert(date[0]);
    alert(date[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_split.htm) method:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var fullDate="August 24, 2014 - September 22, 2014";
    alert(fullDate.split("-")[0]);
    alert(fullDate.split("-")[1]);
});
```

<kbd>[Sample demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5wdbvkv5/2/)</kbd>